# Duda jsp recibe parámetro null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Buenas tardes,

Estoy creando un programa que necesita cargar en una lista los datos que hay en una bbdd en un jsp.
He creado el jsp que recoge los datos de la bbdd y me rellena y ArrayList con ellos, pero cuando se lo paso al servlet e intento recuperar ese array, me da siempre null.
Os dejo la parte necesaria del código por si podéis echarle un vistazo:

El Servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {                            
    try {
        GestorPelicula gp = new GestorPelicula();
        ArrayList<Pelicula> alp = new ArrayList<Marca>();
        alp = gma.recogerPeliculas();
        String nextJSP = "agregar.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
        request.setAttribute("pelis", alp);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AgregarMarcaServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AgregarMarcaServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AgregarMarcaServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

El jsp:

```
<%ArrayList<Pelicula> alpelis= (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("pelis");%>
```

He comprobado la parte del servlet y el array se rellena correctamente, pero no llega a ser recogido por el jsp.
Al comprobar el array o cualquier otra variable, siempre da null.

Si alguien puede ayudarme, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente fragmento de codigo :

```
if(request.getAttribute("pelis") != null)
{
    System.out.println("parametro correcto");
    if( request.getAttribute("pelis")  instanceof java.util.List  )
    {
        System.out.println("El parametro recibido es una lista");
        java.util.ArrayList<Pelicula> alpelis = (java.util.List)request.getAttribute("pelis");
    }
}
else
{
    System.out.println("parametro correcto");
```

Tambien valida el log, puede que en alguna parte este generando una Exception

Espero te sirva
Saludos.